# Why is express.js not liking my routing and not picking up my middleware function?

Tags: node.js, express

Can anyone help me with this message?

```
D:\myProjects\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
    at Function.use (D:\myProjects\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (D:\myProjects\test\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (D:\myProjects\test\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:217:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\myProjects\test\app.js:15:5)
```

app.js

```
const express=require('express');
const app = express();
const config = require('./config/config');
const {getPeopleHandler} = require('./routes/people');
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
const PORT = config.port || 3000;

nunjucks.configure('pages', {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.use('/people', getPeopleHandler);

app.listen(PORT, (err)=> {
    console.log(`up & running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

people.js

```
const express=require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const callAPI = require('../services/api');
const config = require('../config/config');

const getPeople = async (req, res) => {
    const url = config.getPeopledataUrl;
    const response = await callAPI(url);
    res.locals.list = response[1];
    res.render('people.html');
};

router.get('/people', getPeople);

module.exports = getPeople;
```

get-people-handler,js

```
const callAPI = require('../../services/api');
const config = require('../../config/config');

const getPeopleHandler = async (req, res) => {
    console.log('in getPeople')
    const url = config.getPeopledataUrl;
    const response = await callAPI(url);
    console.log(response[1]);
    res.locals.list = response[1];
    res.render('people.html');
};

module.exports = {getPeopleHandler};
```

I think the problem is in app.js where I'm trying to import getPeopleHandler from people.js even though it's not defined there. I've exported the router instead which I'm pretty sure is correct. It's just a case - I think - of using it in app.js somehow. Or have I got this totally wrong?

Comment: Your app.js and people.js both look same. Not sure why you have both js listening to ports. This makes it look like both are different express applications. And yes your import from people.js is not correct

Comment: Wow. That's embarrassing. I mis-pasted. Have now edited the posting so I look like less of a dick.

Comment: **I've exported the router instead which I'm pretty sure is correct** -> Yes, you need to export the router, which is expected by `app.use('/path', router)` in app.js

Comment: That's done it. Thanks Dang.